# Data is not being read in to my ArrayList from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

any help is greatly appreciated! I have been trying to query data from Firebase to have the starting date and end date be today's date, with the start time of 00:00:00 and 23:59:59. I am facing an error that I believe my Firebase data is no longer being read in properly to my ArrayLists. I get the error below:

````
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 7032
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.myapplication.Homepage$1.onDataChange(Homepage.java:119)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
    ```

My code:
````

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.IMarker;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Homepage extends AppCompatActivity{

    private LineChart chart;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private String userID;
    private TextView tvTitle;
    long reference_timestamp;

    ArrayList<Long> acTime = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Long> newAcTime = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Long> acValues = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Entry> result = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

        tvTitle = findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        chart = findViewById(R.id.petChart);
        chart.setDragEnabled(true);
        chart.setScaleEnabled(true);

        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        c1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);

        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 59);
        c2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
        c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        c2.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);

        long startTime = c1.getTimeInMillis()/1000;
        long endTime = c2.getTimeInMillis()/1000;

        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        userID = user.getUid();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/" + userID);
        Query query = reference.orderByKey().startAt(String.valueOf(startTime)).endAt(String.valueOf(endTime));

        System.out.println("Printing reference:" + reference);

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DataSnapshot acSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("Data");

                System.out.println("getting accelerometer values");
                for (DataSnapshot valueSnapshot : acSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    acValues.add(Long.parseLong((valueSnapshot.getValue(String.class))));
                    acTime.add(Long.parseLong((valueSnapshot.getKey())));
                }

                long temp_time;
                for (int i = 0; i < acTime.size(); i++)
                {
                    reference_timestamp = acTime.get(0);
                    System.out.println("Printing acTime.get(0):" + acTime.get(0));
                    temp_time = acTime.get(i) - reference_timestamp;
                    System.out.println("Printing temp_time:" + temp_time);
                    newAcTime.add(temp_time);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < newAcTime.size(); i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(newAcTime.get(i));
                }

                System.out.println("setting results array");
                for (int i = 0; i < acTime.size(); i++)
                {
                    result.add(new Entry(newAcTime.get(i), acValues.get(i)));
                }

                System.out.println("setting dataset");

                Date date = new Date(acTime.get(0)*1000);
                DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
                String formatted = format.format(date);

                tvTitle.setText("Accelerometer Data for " + formatted);




                LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(result, "Magnitude of Accelerometer Data");

                chart.setTouchEnabled(true);
                chart.setDragEnabled(true);
                chart.setScaleEnabled(true);
                chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
                chart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(true);

                chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                chart.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);


                set1.setDrawValues(false);
                set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
                set1.setColor(Color.rgb(0,0,165));
                set1.setLineWidth(1.5f);
                set1.setDrawCircles(true);

                System.out.println("creating arraylist for datasets");
                ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();

                System.out.println("adding dataset to set1");
                dataSets.add(set1);

                System.out.println("creating LineData data2 for datasets");
                LineData data2 = new LineData(dataSets);



                System.out.println("setting the data");
                chart.setData(data2);


                chart.getDescription().setText("");
                IMarker marker = new YourMarkerView(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.marker, reference_timestamp);
                chart.setMarker(marker);

                Legend l = chart.getLegend();

                l.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE);
                l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP);
                l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
                l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
                l.setDrawInside(false);


                XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
                xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE);
                xAxis.setTextSize(16f);
                xAxis.setValueFormatter(new XAxisValueFormatter(reference_timestamp));
//                xAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
//                xAxis.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 192, 56));
                xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
                xAxis.setLabelCount(3);
                xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);


                YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
                leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.INSIDE_CHART);
                leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
                leftAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
                leftAxis.setLabelCount(3);
                leftAxis.setTextSize(16f);
                leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                YAxis rightAxis = chart.getAxisRight();
                rightAxis.setEnabled(false);

                System.out.println("notifying data sets changed");
                chart.notifyDataSetChanged();

                System.out.println("invalidate");
                chart.invalidate();
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data I can't be certain.

I would start by debugging what the content of `dataSnapshot` is at this point as well as `acSnapshot`. I suspect that the following is iterating over an empty list so acTime is empty, causing your lookup for element 0 to be index out of bounds.

```
DataSnapshot acSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("Data");

System.out.println("getting accelerometer values");
for (DataSnapshot valueSnapshot : acSnapshot.getChildren())
```

Also, it may be worth verifying the data is formatted as you expect from the Google Cloud or Firebase console: [https://firebase.google.com/project/{your-project}/firestore/data](https://firebase.google.com/project/%7Byour-project%7D/firestore/data)